# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust, sdl, lifetime

I'm having lifetime issues with a particular function in my code.  I'm following a tutorial in an attempt to learn Rust and SDL.  The tutorial was slightly older and the SDL library has changed since its been written, so I'm following along while also adapting it towards the latest version of Rust-SDL.

The lifetime problem is in this function:

```
pub fn ttf_str_sprite(&mut self, text: &str, font_path: &'static str, size: i32, color: Color) -> Option<Sprite> {
    if let Some(font) = self.cached_fonts.get(&(font_path, size)) {
        return font.render(text).blended(color).ok()
            .and_then(|surface| self.renderer.create_texture_from_surface(&surface).ok())
            .map(Sprite::new)
    }
    //::sdl2_ttf::Font::from_file(Path::new(font_path), size).ok()
    self.ttf_context.load_font(Path::new(font_path), size as u16).ok()
        .and_then(|font| {
            self.cached_fonts.insert((font_path, size), font);
            self.ttf_str_sprite(text, font_path, size, color)
    })
}
```

particularly with the line `self.ttf_context.load_font(Path::new(font_path), size as u16).ok()`.  The commented line above it is the old SDL version's font loading method.

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\phi/mod.rs:57:26
   |
57 |         self.ttf_context.load_font(Path::new(font_path), size as u16).ok()
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn ttf_str_sprite(&'window mut self, text: &str, font_path: &'static str,
              size: i32, color: Color) -> Option<Sprite>
```

The struct object for that implementation looks like this:

```
pub struct Phi<'window> {
    pub events: Events,
    pub renderer: Renderer<'window>,
    pub ttf_context: Sdl2TtfContext,

    cached_fonts: HashMap<(&'static str, i32), ::sdl2_ttf::Font<'window>>
}
```

The method is trying to load a font from Phi's `ttf_context` and load it into the hashmap.  The Rust compiler suggested I add a lifetime to `self` in the function parameters, which, when I did that, caused a cascading effect to adding lifetimes to every method calling the original one, all the way down to `main()` and didn't help anything.

Since I'm still new to Rust, I'm not sure where the lifetime conflict resides or why this is happening.  As a guess, I'm thinking that the `Font` object that is being generated is supposed to die with the end of that method but instead it's being loaded into a hashmap with a lifetime of `'window` and those two conflict.  I don't know enough about Rust to fix that, though, or if that's even correct.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's a smaller example that reproduces the problem:

```rust
struct FontLoader(String);
struct Font<'a>(&'a str);

impl FontLoader {
    fn load(&self) -> Font {
        Font(&self.0)
    }
}

struct Window;

struct Phi<'window> {
    window: &'window Window,
    loader: FontLoader,
    font: Option<Font<'window>>,
}

impl<'window> Phi<'window> {
    fn do_the_thing(&mut self) {
        let font = self.loader.load();
        self.font = Some(font);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:32
   |
20 |         let font = self.loader.load();
   |                                ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     fn do_the_thing(&mut self) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
20 |         let font = self.loader.load();
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'window` as defined on the impl at 18:6...
  --> src/main.rs:18:6
   |
18 | impl<'window> Phi<'window> {
   |      ^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/main.rs:21:21
   |
21 |         self.font = Some(font);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Option<Font<'window>>`
              found `Option<Font<'_>>`
```

The problem is indeed that you have constructed an impossible case. Specifically, the code states these points:

1. `Phi` is going to include a reference to a `Window`. That referred-to value lives for the lifetime `'window`.
2. `Phi` is going to include a `Font`, which contains a reference. That referred-to value lives for the lifetime `'window`.
3. `FontLoader` returns a `Font` which contains a reference to a value with the lifetime **of the loader**. This is due to lifetime inference, which when expanded looks like:

   ```rust
   impl FontLoader {
       fn load<'a>(&'a self) -> Font<'a> {
           Font(&self.0)
       }
   }
   ```

   I highly encourage adding `#![deny(rust_2018_idioms)]` to your crate, which will disallow this specific type of lifetime inference.

Then the code attempts to load a `Font` from the `FontLoader` in `Phi`, which **does not** have the lifetime `'window` and store that `Font` into `Phi`. `FontLoader` (and thus `Font`) does not live long enough, so it cannot be stored in `Phi`.

The compiler has correctly prevented incorrect code.

---

Your next attempt would probably be to introduce a second lifetime:

```rust
struct Phi<'window, 'font> {
    window: &'window Window,
    loader: FontLoader,
    font: Option<Font<'font>>,
}

impl<'window, 'font> Phi<'window, 'font> {
    fn do_the_thing(&'font mut self) {
        let font = self.loader.load();
        self.font = Some(font);
    }
}
```

This will actually compile, but probably doesn't do what you want. See [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) for further information.

More likely, you want to take a reference to the font loader:

```rust
struct Phi<'a> {
    window: &'a Window,
    loader: &'a FontLoader,
    font: Option<Font<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Phi<'a> {
    fn do_the_thing(&mut self) {
        let font = self.loader.load();
        self.font = Some(font);
    }
}
```

Here, I've renamed the lifetime as it isn't strictly for the window anymore.

Comment: __FontLoader (and thus Font) does not live long enough__: Isn't the lifetime of `FontLoader` the same as the Phi that contains it ?

Comment: @CarlLevasseur yes, the lifetime of `FontLoader` and its containing `Phi` are the same. Why do you ask?

Comment: Doesn't that mean it has the `'window` lifetime then ? i don't understand why it does not live long enough if its lifetime is the same as the `Phi` object and therefore, the same as `Phi.font` ? In what case would the font loader be free'd before then end of the `'window` lifetime ?

Comment: @CarlLevasseur *In what case would the font loader be free'd before then end of the `'window` lifetime* — in **every** case, I believe. *Doesn't that mean it has the `'window` lifetime* — no. It contains a reference that has the `window` lifetime, but itself has a different lifetime.

Comment: I'm trying to understand a `main` that would crash had the top example you provided been allowed to compile. Is this one? https://gist.github.com/rust-play/e5e9aa7374de695f896717f058d8c48c In that `font_str` might have been freed before we print?

Comment: @MarioIshac since lifetimes prevent incorrect code from compiling, you need to use raw pointers to demonstrate the problem. [Here's one such possibility](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2b5db621ea4921dcc1aa14b6733d2ab8). Note that the pointer now points to an invalid location.