# Rust - cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust's lifetimes concept and can't wrap my head around a particular piece of code. I've been working with Rust's SDL bindings and its Texture/TextureCreator classes and the problem basically boils down to the following scheme:

```rust
struct Creator;

impl Creator {
    fn create(&self) -> Creature {
        Creature { creator: &self }
    }
}

struct Creature<'a> {
    creator: &'a Creator,
}

struct MyStruct<'a> {
    creator: Creator,
    creatures: Vec<Creature<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn new() -> MyStruct<'a> {
        MyStruct {
            creatures: Vec::new(),
            creator: Creator,
        }
    }

    fn create(&mut self) {
        let new_creature = self.creator.create();
        self.creatures.push(new_creature);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new();
    my_struct.create();
}
```

The actual problem lies inside `MyStruct::create` method. If I try to compile the above code I get:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to con
flicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:27:41
   |
27 |         let new_creature = self.creator.create();
   |                                         ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 define
d on the method body at 26:5...
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 | /     fn create(&mut self) {
27 | |         let new_creature = self.creator.create();
28 | |         self.creatures.push(new_creature);
29 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:27:28
   |
27 |         let new_creature = self.creator.create();
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on t
he impl at 18:6...
  --> src/main.rs:18:6
   |
18 | impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected Creature<'a>
              found Creature<'_>
```

The interesting thing is that when I comment out this line inside `MyStruct::create`:

```rust
self.creatures.push(new_creature);
```

it compiles just fine.

My assumption is that it can lead to the following problem - a newly created `new_creature` has a reference to the `creator` which is owned by `my_struct`. Now, if that `new_creature` is then owned by the `creatures` vector, I can't really call any method on `my_struct` that borrows itself as `mut` because at that point there will be:

- a reference to `creator` inside `my_struct`
- a mutable reference to `my_struct` inside the method's body (and therefore to `my_struct.creator`)

However, this is how I see it from my point of view. From the compiler's standpoint it's about lifetimes and don't quite get it. So I have the two following questions:

1. Why does the compiler complain about lifetimes in this case?
2. How can I go about storing `Vec<Creature>` in a struct? Should I make sure that I don't keep both `Creator` and `Vec<Creature>` in the same struct to avoid the aforementioned issue?

Comment: See also [Is there a way to store a texture inside a struct using rust-sdl2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56051593/155423)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is trying to tell you that it is expecting a very specific lifetime in `Creature<'a>` but the code actually produces a generic lifetime `Creature<'_>`. That is, the lifetime bound on `Creature` must be `'a` but you are writing method `create()` for *any* lifetime `'_`.

Change `create()` to

```
fn create(&'a mut self) {
    let new_creature = self.creator.create();
    self.creatures.push(new_creature);
}
```

and it will compile: Instead of "any lifetime `&mut self` could ever have" you now have "`&mut self` must have lifetime 'a".

Comment: I've already tried it but it doesn't solve my problem at all. If I call `my_struct.create()` once again, the compiler tells me:

`error[E0499]: cannot borrow 'my_struct' as mutable more than once at a time`

Comment: While this technically solves the error, it makes the value immovable. Try adding `{my_struct}` at the end of `main`.