# `format!` requires static lifetime?

Tags: rust

Here is a minimal reproducible sample:

```
use std::fmt::{self, Debug, Formatter};

pub trait Apple {}

impl Debug for dyn Apple {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("Apple")
    }
}

struct Basket<'a> {
    apples: Vec<Box<dyn Apple + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Basket<'a> {
    fn f(&self) {
        let x = format!("{:?}", self.apples);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:17:17
   |
17 |         let x = format!("{:?}", self.apples);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 15:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:15:6
   |
15 | impl<'a> Basket<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:17:17
   |
17 |         let x = format!("{:?}", self.apples);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `(&std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<dyn Apple>>,)`
              found `(&std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<(dyn Apple + 'a)>>,)`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:17:33
   |
17 |         let x = format!("{:?}", self.apples);
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `std::fmt::Debug`
              found `std::fmt::Debug`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

`format!` should only borrow `self.apples` for a *very short period* of time (only borrow during its formatting process). However, it even requires `self.apples` to have the `'static` lifetime.

**EDIT:** Now I see why is that, after kind help from comments and other answers. According to @Shepmaster's suggestion, I move this part of content into an answer.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270052/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicting-requirements

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. If I supply a `trait Req {}` I get ``error[E0277]: `dyn Req` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug` ``, not the one you claim. The problem is in some other code than what is in the question.

Comment: Not reroduced on stable and nightly channels, both 2018 and 2015 edition: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dabaa88484570326ef48780dbc5c63fd

Comment: Now reproducible, **question is edited!** Thanks friends!

Comment: @chuigda_whitegive Thanks for your "non-reproducibile" sample! I find out where I am wrong.

Comment: @trentcl Question edited. Thanks!

Comment: @IronMan Seems a little bit different. Question edited. Thanks!

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for your suggestion! I have moved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of [default trait object lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes), `impl Debug for dyn Apple` is shorthand for `impl Debug for dyn Apple + 'static`.

To write an implementation for non-`'static` trait objects, you can override this default lifetime with an explicit one:

```
impl<'a> Debug for dyn Apple + 'a
```

Comment: Very clear and solved my issue! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see the reason after @chuigda_whitegive 's "non-reproducible" sample:

This is wrong

```
pub trait Apple {}

impl Debug for dyn Apple {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("Apple")
    }
}
```

but should do this

```
pub trait Apple: Debug {}
```

I still do not understand, *why* I should not `impl Debug for dyn Apple`. It compiles in other cases and it sounds reasonable ("when debugging, we should output the `Apple` string").

---

*EDIT*

Now I see how to do a two-letter modification to the original question. One more anonymous lifetime and this compiles:

```
use std::fmt::{Debug, Formatter};

pub trait Apple {}

impl Debug for dyn Apple + '_ {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("Apple")
    }
}

struct Basket<'a> {
    apples: Vec<Box<dyn Apple + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Basket<'a> {
    fn f(&self) {
        let x = format!("{:?}", self.apples);
    }
}
```

For why this is the case, please see @Matt Brubeck 's answer.